# Inject JavaScript before html loaded with Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using Android WebView to load a simple HTML page. The HTML depends on a tiny piece of Javascript code.

I need to inject the Javascript before html loaded. So I do it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;
    Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,JsResult result) {
                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
            }
        });


        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new myListener());
    }

    class myListener implements OnClickListener{

        int mCount = 1;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            System.out.println("Load test page=>"+mCount+" times");
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var output='This string is defined before html loaded.'");
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
            mCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
alert(output);
</script>
<head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

**The JS and HTML works fine when I click the button first time. But when I click the button to execute the load again, it failed.**

Logs:

```
Load test page=>1 times
Load test page=>2 times
Uncaught ReferenceError: output is not defined at file:///android_asset/test.html:5
Load test page=>3 times
Uncaught ReferenceError: output is not defined at file:///android_asset/test.html:5
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) , render the variant into HTML (e.g. string replacement) then load the string as a page.

Answer (score -1):

This may seem like a long-winded approach, but could you have your android code write the js code to a file, then reference that file in your html file?